# Converting Prelude as defined in ghc sources, to readable format as outlined in Haskell 98 Report

Tags: haskell, ghc

In [Standard Prelude](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/standard-prelude.html) the definition of the Prelude module is given :

```
module Prelude (
    module PreludeList, module PreludeText, module PreludeIO,
    Bool(False, True),
    Maybe(Nothing, Just),
    ....
```

In the ghc sources, it seems that the Prelude module is defined (in a "Literate programming" fashion) in `compiler/prelude/PrelNames.lhs`. Is there any way for me to convert this literate file into the (more readable) format shown in the Haskell 98 Report?

p.s. I am aware that I can browse the Prelude documentation at [Prelude documentation](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6-latest/html/libraries/base-4.6.0.1/Prelude.html) but I want to view the prelude source as outlined in Haskell 98 Report.

Comment: `PrelNames.lhs` doesn't contain the implementation, only the IDs of Prelude functions that GHC needs to know about. The actual implementation is in `base` (click the "Source" link [here](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6-latest/html/libraries/base-4.6.0.1/src/Prelude.html)).

Comment: @MikhailGlushenkov Ah excellent. How come this file does not come with ghc in https://github.com/ghc/ghc ? Maybe if you could put your response as an answer (as opposed to a comment) then I can mark this post as answered (green tick).

Comment: http://hdiff.luite.com/packages/archive/haskell98/

Comment: @artella If you run `./sync-all get` in the GHC source tree, it will check out a working copy of `base` under `libraries/base`. See [here](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Commentary/Libraries).

Comment: Just found Prelude.hs in https://github.com/ghc/packages-base

Comment: @MikhailGlushenkov That's great, just ran `./sync-all get` and now I am seeing the Prelude modules in `libraries/haskell2010/Prelude.hs`,`libraries/haskell98/Prelude.hs`,`libraries/base/Prelude.hs`.